# Probabilities from ecdf and normalised data - is this acceptable difference? (using R)

Tags: r, normal-distribution, predictive-models, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have a dataset of 500 observations, definitely not normally distributed:[image] The minimum is around 50 000 in the data. If I use ecdf to predict e.g. 100 000, I get:

```
>ecdf(sfix)(100000)
>[1] 0.002
```

I have then normalised the data using the "bestNormalize" package:

```
Based off these, bestNormalize chose:
Standardized Box Cox Transformation with 500 nonmissing obs.:
 Estimated statistics:
 - lambda = 0.2468158 
 - mean (before standardization) = 373.0962 
 - sd (before standardization) = 102.0227
```

But now if I predict for the same value (100 000), this is what happens:

```
>pred <- predict(bn_sfix, newdata = 100000)
>pnorm(pred)
[1] 0.001280998
```

The difference between the ecdf prediction and the pnorm to me seems quite big (0.0007190017,
or 0.2% vs 0.13% probability). (In case anyone is wondering why I transformed it: because I would need to predict for values lower than the minimum in the dataset).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this the level of exactness you can get via this method; and is this difference acceptable? What does the Statistics community think? Thank you!

Comment: Despite what the name might suggest, normalizing data does not turn it into normally distributed data. Neither does standardizing.

Comment: Could you include what you're trying to accomplish? Is it to predict the outcome when the predictor is $100,000$? Because there might be better approaches entirely.

Comment: With just $n=500$ values, you should be unconcerned with differences up to $1/n=0.002.$  They arise because linear interpolation is not the same when data are nonlinearly transformed.  Please plot both ECDFs for the lowest quantiles so you can *see* what's going on.

Comment: @whuber, thanks, that _was_ revealing (even if I don't quite understand what is going on yet)!

Comment: @FransRodenburg, thanks for replying. I thought that after normalising and standardising data can be used for the parametric tests... otherwise what would be the point? What I am trying to accomplish is this: I need to predict probabilities for much lower values than the minimum in my dataset. (I am aware that this is not a robust procedure, I just need it for kind of a pointer.) My idea was that if I have n = 500 and min = 50 000, if I transform it into normal distribution, I can predict for any (low) value?

Comment: @Frans Leaving the possible terminology issue aside (of whether this should be called 'normalizing' or not), nevertheless the OP appears to have transformed the data via a Box-Cox transformation, and does in fact appear to be attempting to make the sample somewhat closer to normal. I mention this because I sense some potential of your words to lead the OP to think they're not doing what they did.